Three array scatter plot using Numpy and Matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
x =[24,73,94,8,26,80,89,23,7,50] 
 
y =[52,98,48,39,50,84,76,96,76,9]

z=[14,56,79,21,42,67,5,55,27,91,10]
 
plt.scatter(x, y,z)
 
# To show the plot
plt.show()

I can only give 2 arrays in order to get a scatter plot. What should I do in order to get the 3 array in a single scatter plot without converting into a 3d array plotting.
I also tried the below code but it is not possible.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x =np.array[24,73,94,8,26,80,89,23,7,50] 
 
y =np.array[52,98,48,39,50,84,76,96,76,9]

z=np.array[14,56,79,21,42,67,5,55,27,91,10]
 
plt.scatter(x, y,z)
 
# To show the plot
plt.show()


Yes, by using 3D array we can plot in 3D, but
the answer for 3D array plotting is:
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


# Creating dataset 
z = np.random.randint(100, size =(50)) 
x = np.random.randint(80, size =(50)) 
y = np.random.randint(60, size =(50)) 

# Creating figure 
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7)) 
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d") 

# Creating plot 
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "red") 
plt.title("3D Scatter Plot") 

# show plot 
plt.show()

